# Expansion of a Complex Product

Tags: complex-numbers, contest-math

I was doing a Putnam problem whose solution stated that 
$$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi}\prod_{k=1}^m \left(e^{ikx} + e^{-ikx}\right)dx = \sum_{e_k = \pm 1}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{ix(e_1+2e_2+...+me_m)}dx,$$
over all $2^m$ $m$-tuples $(e_1, e_2, ..., e_m)$.

Where exactly does this come from?

Comment: I think it follows from the fact that $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i\alpha x}\,dx$ equals $0$ if $\alpha\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ and equals $1$ if $\alpha=0$. Expanding the product and seeing what is left after integrating yields a sum like that on the right (I don't have time to make this a proper answer but believe this is the right idea).

Comment: @Clayton I don't think so, only because the solution uses that fact in the next step of the problem to simplify this sum.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  This is just expanding the product and considering each term.  For a given term of the product, you either take the positive or negative exponent from the binomial in the product.  Then, it's just linearity of integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really just an expansion of the product. Say $m=2$. Then $$(e^{i1x}+e^{-i1x})(e^{i2x}+e^{-i2x})=e^{ix(1+2)}+e^{ix(1-2)}+e^{ix(-1+2)}+e^{ix(-1-2)}$$
In the general case you need to add all terms $e^{ix(\pm1\pm2\pm3\pm...\pm m)}$

Answer (score 0):

Attempt at a solution:

$$\newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}} \newcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}
\cos z = \frac{\e^{\i z} + \e^{-\i z}}2$$

Substituting $z=kx$ gives

$$2\cos kx = \e^{\i kx} + \e^{-\i kx}$$

$$\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^m \bigl(\e^{\i kx} + \e^{-\i kx}\bigr) &=
\prod_{k=1}^m(2\cos kx) \\
&= 2\cos(x) \times 2\cos(2x) \times \cdots \times 2\cos(mx) \\
&= 2^m \cos(x)\cdots\cos(mx)
\end{align}$$

While remembering $k$ stepped up as integers, slap that back into the integral:

$$2^m\int_0^{2π} \cos(x)\cdots\cos(mx) \, \mathrm dx$$

On the other side, you have your basic

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\e^{\i x(e_1+2e_2+...+me_m)}\,\mathrm dx &= \left.\frac1{\i(e_1+2e_2+...+me_m)} \, \e^{\i x(e_1+2e_2+...+me_m)}\right\rvert_{0}^{2π} \\[2ex]
&= \frac{\cos 2πE + \i\sin 2πE - \cos 0 -\i\sin0}{\i E}
\end{align}$$

I really don’t know what to do with that. Hope it gets the train of thought rolling.

Comment: The problem was to show when the cos integral was non-zero.  I turned it into the exponential product intentionally :D

Comment: @math783625 I’m not sure I’m following

Comment: What is the big $E$?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik All the junk $e_1 + \cdots$, the stuff that stayed the same in the denominator next to $\mathrm i$. It was just to tidy things up.

Comment: @let'shaveabreakdown what you've done reversed the progress I made for the problem.  I turned the cosine integral into what I had, and you turned what I had into the cos integral.

Comment: @let'shaveabreakdown to finish the problem, the integral is 0 unless E is 0, so you need to find the possible m for which E is 0.

Comment: @math783625 Well in that case I’m of the opinion that your question could have been more clearly stated.

Comment: Yes, sorry, but I was asking where the equality came from, which you haven't really showed anyway.  Nevertheless, thanks for the help.